# NetLogo and R: Determine Point on Curve using Simulated Ant Colony

Tags: r, regression, netlogo

I have built a simulation in R that produces a monotonic concave curve (up to an asymptote). The standard thing to do next would be to make predictions using the regression model of the curve.

However, I would like to do something a bit different. I would like to simulate an ant colony in NetLogo and trace their path along the curve that I generated in R.

I am new to NetLogo and I know there is an R interface, but I have never used it, nor coded anything in NetLogo.

**My question is:** would it be difficult to implement such a scenario in NetLogo?

Comment: This question is probably too broad for Stack Overflow. Offhand, though, I don't see any barrier to doing what you're describing.